# How can I add additional fields to my Model in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Audience(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.title().replace('_', ' ')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
```

When I use it in another model, I get a list of all the Audiences in the DB.

`audience = models.ForeignKey(Audience)`

In my final view I get a list of items from the DB in a dropdown. EX:

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3

I'm trying to append a custom value that doesn't come from the DB. EX:

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- CUSTOM_VAL (appended value, not in the database)

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please share your current views and forms code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following line to your views

```py
form.fields['audience'].choices += [('optional_val','optional_val')]
```